# Move Listview Position while speking it with texttospeech

Tags: android, xamarin

I have a ListView which i let read position by position by tts.
I want to scroll to the list position that is actually beeing read.

When I start my read method the position jumps immediatly to the last list position, bcs tts creates a speech-queue async and then plays it.

Is there a way to move the listposition synchronously?

```
  _btnspeak.Click += delegate {

            //vokabeln is a List of Vokabel
            if (vokabeln.Count > 0)
            {
                // _listpos is the current position in the list
                int _listpos = 0;


                while (_listpos < vokabeln.Count)

                {
                    Vokabel v = vokabeln.ElementAt(_listpos);

                    _lvvokabeln.SmoothScrollToPosition(_listpos);


                    textToSpeechd.Speak(v.DE, QueueMode.Add, null);
                    textToSpeechd.PlaySilence(200, QueueMode.Add, null);


                    _listpos += 1;

                }
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood, you want to scroll only when the list item has been read, so you need to wait until the item is read in order to read the next one.

Regarding your question:

> Is there a way to move the listposition synchronously?

That´s exactly what you are doing, the `while` loop runs until the end in no time (synchronously), and that´s why it scrolls down to the last position.

You need to make it asynchronously:

```
b.Click += async delegate { // make the delate async
    if(vokabeln.Count > 0)
    {
        while(_listpos < vokabeln.Count)
        {
            // do scroll
            // do speech

            // set here the duration of the speech. 1000 = 1 second
            await Task.Delay(3000); 
        }
    }
};
```

I don´t know the TextToSpeech API, but the best scenario would be if you could get the duration of a particular speech, then `await Task.Delay(duration)` like the sample above.

If you don´t have that option, but instead the API provides an event when the speech is done/finished, instead of a `while` loop you could do something like:

1. set counter to 0
2. scroll to first item
3. do speech of first item
4. listen to finished event of the speech
5. counter ++
6. if counter <= total items => do the same with the next one

Comment: thanks for your help. I just adapted the delay as a function of the texttospeak length and it works perfect!!!

Answer (score 0):

you can use `getListView().smoothScrollToPosition(position);`
to scroll the listview to current position

Comment: i use this but it jumps immediately to the last list position.

Comment: please share what you have tried, it would be helpful to help you

Comment: it seems that I need somthing that makes tts speak word by word, not generating a speech queue.